# regex anchors in oXygen find/replace dialog with XPath

Tags: xml, regex, xpath, oxygenxml

Is there a way to anchor a regex expression in the oXygen find/replace dialog with an XPath constraint such that it will match the beginning of the matching XPath string? So far, "^" will not match on anything when I try to use the dialog with XPath.

E.g., given an input document

```
<fruit>
    <apple>Graham</apple>
</fruit>
```

the regular expression

```
^Graham
```

with XPath
    `fruit/apple`

will not select anything. If I don't enter anything in the XPath, `^` correctly selects the beginning of the line. The "regular expression" box is checked and I have tested my XPath. If I take the anchor out of my regex, it will correctly match on the string. The only thing I can't get to work is the anchor. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

In Oxygen's Find/Replace window, `^` and `$` are relative to lines in the file. Even when you specify an XPath filter, they don't match on the start or end of the XPath element.

`^` matches the position before the first character in the string. `^` cannot match at the position before "Graham" because it is not preceded by a newline--with or without the XPath, the preceding character is not a newline. The anchor by itself is matching the start of each line because the preceding character in those instances is a newline.

`\A` only ever matches at the start of the string; however, XPath does not support `\A` or `\Z`. Normally you'd be restricted to caret when using XPath in Oxygen's Find/Replace dialog due to XPath's substandard support for Perl-like regexes; however, the Find/Replace regex support in Oxygen is the full set of Java regular expressions, which is not the same as XPath regex; therefore, you can use `\A` or `\Z`, you're not stuck with just `^` and `$`.

In Oxygen if one wants to match the start of an XML element, then use Find/Replace with the element in question, such as `<apple[^>]+>Graham` or better just use the XPath field to find `//apple[matches(., '^Graham')]` because in XPath syntax `^` and `$` are relative to start/end of strings, not lines.

One of the semi-documented Saxon extensions is to allow Java regex constructs in XPath when you use the `!` flag. For example, enable `\b` (word boundary) and positive/negative lookahead.